# .NET Core web, Umbraco 10, custom controllers and views

Tags: view, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, umbraco

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web app totally build in .NET Core: it has dozens of custom models, view models, services for data validation, views, forms, web apis, ajax calls and so on.

Recently I have been asked to make some contents editable: in summary, some pages will be almost static (texts and images to edit/add/delete), the most part will be dynamic (models/viewmodels/CRUD etc) but also these pages some 'static' sections can be updated.

I am trying and studying some CMS like Umbraco (and Piranha, but this seems a bit limited), I read some tutorials but I still haven't come out to a decent solution.

My questions are:

1. First of all, is it possible to install Umbraco on an existing web app solution? Or must I first create an Umbraco project and then import the rest of the solution?
2. Now I know how to create a page and insert content; but every attempt to create a custom view that renders a custom view model AND has editable contents from the dashboard (a title, a paragraph with explanations and so on) were failure. I mean, I can access the model view properties but not the 'static' sections of the page.

Some sample code: a trivial class

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

The controller:

```
public class PersonController : SurfaceController
{
    public PersonController(
        IUmbracoContextAccessor umbracoContextAccessor,
        IUmbracoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
        ServiceContext services,
        AppCaches appCaches,
        IProfilingLogger profilingLogger,
        IPublishedUrlProvider publishedUrlProvider)
        : base(umbracoContextAccessor, databaseFactory, services, appCaches, profilingLogger, publishedUrlProvider)
    {
    }

    [Route("/person")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Person person = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Pippo" }; 
        return View(person);
    }

    [Route("/person/about")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        Person person = new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Pluto" };
        return View(person);
    }
}
```

The view, created in Umbraco

```
@using UmbraTest.Models
@model Person
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Master.cshtml";
}

<h1>Hi, your Id is @Model.Id</h1>
<p>@Model.Name</p>
```

But I want to insert other html content directly from the CMS.

This is more a request for an advice: as said, I have dozens of controllers/views. I have read about SurfaceControllers, MvcRendererController in Umbraco. This means that I should edit all my dozens of controllers, supposing I can solve point 1) and 2). Is it really worth with it? Maybe it's better and less hard to reject the request and answer "don't worry, whenever you have to edit some content, I'll do for you".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing web app and need some CMS'able content, I would look at a headless CMS. Umbraco does offer a version of this called 'Heartcore'. For more details have a look here:

https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-heartcore/what-is-umbraco-heartcore/

Basically, a headless CMS is a content management system without the front-end rendering. So in your case, you could add all of you CMS content to this application and fetch this data from your existing web app via API calls.

I think this approach is the easier way to achieve what you want without ripping your existing web app apart.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello Ben D, thank you for the reply and the advice.

I forgot to say in my post that I had already taken a look to Umbraco Heartcore but I (or better, my company) cannot pay the license for the number of users needed (at least 3)
Yet, an headless CMS solution is interesting. Just need to look for cheaper soltions
Thank you again

Comment: @bitdiego there are plenty of open-source headless CMS platforms out there. Hopefully you can find one that works. I've only ever used Umbraco, so can't really recommend one though. Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, and indeed maybe I found it: Squidex, I have just started to play around with it and looks interesting. And simple...
Thank you again